# favicon always download as a file instead of show on the tab

Tags: favicon

On my page, there is a link to the favicon: favicon.ico. when I open my page, browser always starts download as a file.

I've searched everywhere for a solution, but got no answer.

I don't want to downloaded it, what can be the problem ?

```
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
</head>
```

Comment: Is it possible that my Spring boot serurity configuration problem?

Comment: You're probably not serving the right mime-type. I also don't think `image/icon` is correct here. Might need to be `image/x-icon`

Comment: sorry，just checked, it is `image/x-icon`.